# Erro no retorno de Web Service NuSOAP

Tags: php, web-service, laravel-4, soap

Estou desenvolvendo um web service com NuSOAP no Laravel 4.

A classe que eu estou usando é a https://github.com/noiselabs/NoiselabsNuSOAPBundle

**Server**

```
Route::any('ws/server', function()
{
    $server = new \soap_server;

    $server->configureWSDL('server.hello','urn:server.hello', Request::url());

    $server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = 'urn:server.hello';

    $server->register('hello',
        array('name' => 'xsd:string'),
        array('return' => 'xsd:string'),
        'urn:server.hello',
        'urn:server.hello#hello',
        'rpc',
        'encoded',
        'Retorna o nome'
    );

    function hello($name)
    {
        return 'Hello '.$name;
    }

    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
    return Response::make($server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1'));
});
```

**Cliente**

```
Route::get('ws/client/hello', function()
{
    $client = new \nusoap_client('http://localhost/teste_laravel/public/ws/server?wsdl', true);

    $err = $client->getError();
    if ($err)
    {
        echo "Erro no construtor<pre>".$err."</pre>";
    }

    $result = $client->call('hello',array('Renato'));

    if ($client->fault)
    {
        echo "Falha<pre>".print_r($result)."</pre>";
    }
    else
    {
        $err = $client->getError();

        if ($err)
        {
            echo "Erro<pre>".print_r($err)."</pre>";
        }
        else
        {
            print_r($result);
        }
    }
});
```

No retorno tá trazendo esse erro.

> `Array ( [faultcode] => SOAP-ENV:Client [faultactor] => [faultstring] => error in msg parsing: xml was empty, didn't parse! [detail] => ) Falha 1`

Quando faço o server com PHP puro e o cliente com Laravel da certo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi desse jeito.

```
$rawPostData = file_get_contents("php://input");
return Response::make($server->service($rawPostData), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1'));
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685157/web-service-nusoap-laravel-4/21685649

Comment: Você pode aceitar a resposta aí na esquerda.

Answer (score 1):

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/files/nusoap/
>
> Last Update: 2011-01-13

Isso não responde exatamente sua pergunta, porém vai resolver seu erro. No passado, quando tive que trabalhar com RESTService em PHP, eu usei o Nusoap porque ele era o melhor documentado e muitas referências citavam ele. Porém o que eu acabei percebendo na prática é que ele já foi muito útil em tempos antigos, mas PHP evoluiu e outras bibliotecas evoluíram mais rápido.

**O Nusoap é, basicamente, um projeto que parou no tempo**. Ele já foi bom, porém **se encontrar um erro com ele, você não terá chance de resolver senão deixar de usá-lo ou fazer em PHP puro**. Recomendo fortemente que se ele não estiver fazendo algo trivial, é extremamente provável que se for caçar a fundo vai ver alguma parte dele que precisaria ser completamente reescrita, a ponto de que vale mais a pena não usá-lo caso ele não funcione perfeitamente.

Essa pergunta não responde exatamente seu problema, mas certamente vai evitar muita dor de cabeça.