# Qual a diferença entre SOAP e NuSOAP?

Tags: php, web-service, soap

Estou tendo dificuldades em entender o processo de criação de um WebService em PHP.

Criei um *server* que faz a seguinte chamada:

```
<?php
  require_once "lib/nusoap.php";

  $soap = new soap_server;

  $soap->configureWSDL('WS-WebCodeFree', 'http://localhost/ws-webcodefree/');

  $soap->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = 'http://soapinterop.org/xsd/';

  $soap->register(
        'info',
        array(),        
        array('x' => 'xsd:string'),
        'http://soapinterop.org/'
    );

$soap->service(isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '');

function info(){
    return "WebCodeFree - Desenvolvimento Web.";
}
```

No lado do cliente:

```
<?php
    include "lib/nusoap.php";

    $client =  new SoapClient('http://localhost/web-service/ws-webcodefree.php?wsdl');

    $result1 = $client->call('info');
```

Ele me retorna o erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("call")
>   is not a valid method for this service in
>   C:\GitHub\voxy\app\retorno\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\GitHub\voxy\app\retorno\index.php(3): SoapClient->__call('call',
>   Array) #1 C:\GitHub\voxy\app\retorno\index.php(3):
>   SoapClient->call('info') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\GitHub\voxy\app\retorno\index.php on line 3

Me parece haver um conflito entre NuSoap e SOAP, pelo que li.

Se eu trocar as chamadas, pra `nusoap_client` na chamada do cliente, resolve.

Mas queria saber de fato, onde está o problema, e qual a diferença entre eles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mensagem de erro:

> Nusoap “SOAP-ENV: Xml was empty, didn't parse” Message

tem uma solução aparente para essa mensagem que é adicionar um elemento a mais nessa parte:

```
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) 
    ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA 
    : file_get_contents("php://input");
```

[ou seja, o `file_get_contents("php://input")`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5403/54880) e também eu fiz alterações nos dois arquivos, faltou `return` na `function` e estava fazendo a chamada errada no cliente, por isso do erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("call") is not a valid method for this

e para funcionar [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.soapclient.php) deve ser configurado um [SoapServer](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.soapserver.php), e realmente a `lib` utilizado funciona independente das funções nativas e não são relacionadas.

---

***Código Completo e Funcional:***

---

***Server***

```
<?php

  require_once "lib/nusoap.php";

  $soap = new soap_server;

  $soap->configureWSDL('WS-WebCodeFree', 'http://localhost/ws-webcodefree/');

  $soap->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = 'http://soapinterop.org/xsd/';

  $soap->register('info',
      array(),        
      array('return' => 'xsd:string'),
      'http://soapinterop.org/'
  );

  function info()
  {
    return "WebCodeFree - Desenvolvimento Web.";
  }

  $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) 
    ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA 
    : file_get_contents("php://input");

  $soap->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

***Client***

```
<?php
    include "lib/nusoap.php";

    $client = new nusoap_client('http://localhost/ge1/soap_server.php?wsdl', 'wsdl');

    echo $client->call('info');
```

***Observação:***

- `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` [é um recurso obsoleto e foi removido desde o PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php), e para solucionar o problema é utilizado o `file_get_contents("php://input")` [como descrito na documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php)

---

Esse mesmo código pode ser escrito facilmente assim com [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.soapclient.php) e [SoapServer](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.soapserver.php):

***Server***

```
<?php

    function info()
    {
        return "WebCodeFree - Desenvolvimento Web.";
    }
    $options = array(
        'uri' => 'http://localhost/s.php',
        'location' => 'http://localhost/s.php'
    );
    $server = new SoapServer(null,$options);
    $server->addFunction('info');
    $server->handle();
```

***Client***

```
<?php

    $options = array(
        'uri' => 'http://localhost/s.php',
        'location' => 'http://localhost/s.php'
    );
    $client = new SoapClient(null, $options);

    echo $client->info();
```

a função nativa nos da muito flexibilidade.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php)
- [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.soapclient.php)
- [SoapServer](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.soapserver.php)
- [locaWeb - Utilizando SOAP com PHP](https://ajuda.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Utilizando_SOAP_com_PHP)

Comment: você teria algum exemplo em SOAP nativo, em PHP ?

Comment: @BrunnoSena já fiz a edição com um exemplo referente ao seu com a biblioteca ... !!! dá uma olhada!

Comment: Ok, vi agora.

Uma outra pergunta. Caso eu faça o WebService com NuSOAP. Eu consigo me comunicar de outras linguagens, somente com a URL?
Se eu quiser colocar a disposição de algum parceiro, pra consumirem esse WebService, eles conseguirão ? Ou somente com o SOAP nativo?

O que você me recomendaria ?

Comment: sim .. @BrunnoSena, esse que esta na sua pergunta não gera WSDL o correto é sempre gerar, fiz de acordo com a pergunta, mas, sim é pelo endereço que é consumido!

Comment: Ok, @virgilio-novic vi agora. Uma outra pergunta. Caso eu faça o WebService com NuSOAP. Eu consigo me comunicar de outras linguagens, somente com a URL? Se eu quiser colocar a disposição de algum parceiro, pra consumirem esse WebService, eles conseguirão ? Ou somente com o SOAP nativo? O que você me recomendaria ?

Comment: Sim essa é a idéia principal de existir WebService que outras linguagens e clientes a consumam, mas, hoje em dia estão utlizando o que tem um melhor desempenho que é os `json` os famoso WebApi.